# disable flow warnings about untyped variables

Tags: flowtype

I like to use flow for some reasons (like auto-completion) but I dislike that it forces me to type anything. Right now I find myself spending a lot of time defining useless types just because I want to get rid of warnings that tell me to specify the type.

Can we tell flow to automaticly imply `any` instead of forcing us to write it behind any variable and function declaration?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you're not adding any types, and you're just marking everything as `any`, then why are you using flow at all? You aren't going to get useful autocomplete on variables typed `any`.

Comment: So you just want to use Flow for autocomplete for global JS APIs then? It doesn't really aim to support that case, and it seems relatively uncommon so I'm not sure they'd want to. You'd have to manually say things are `any`, but then you don't have autocomplete on any of your own code.

Comment: First, I would like to be able to share code between projects that use flow and projects that do not. Whenever someone asks me to send a snippet for this or that, he has to remove all of the flow stuff. On the other hand I cannot simply copy snippets to my codebase because it is not typed and flow is constanly reporting that as a problem. 

I think that we can make use of flow without having to type the whole codebase, especially for prototypes. Typing stuff should help us as developers and should not be the cause if writing a lot of useless code (from my point of view).

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply not possible with Flow. Its type system depends on each module's exports having declared types. If you import code from an untyped module, Flow can't infer anything about it. Similarly, if you use a typed module from an untyped one, Flow can't tell you much about it.

I definitely empathize with the desire for types to be a helpful tool of thought. Flow's type inference is really useful to avoid having to write types everywhere. But in order for it to do that inference or detect problems, it does need some help from the programmer.

Comment: I get your point, really. I have worked with different type systems so far, but flow is the most annoying right now. There are open issues for months (especially for React stuff) and I think that is okay because good things need time. However I would like to start using flow for those packages, functions and variables where I need it, while not having to put "any" at any other position, just because the console gets flooded by errors/warnings otherwise. At least why not give us an option for that?